# reCAPTCHA v2 reset not working with ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, recaptcha

I have checkboxes that need to confirm they are not being checked by bots over and over.  I first setup reCAPTCHA V3.  It only returns .9 as a score and the bots continue to enable and disable the checkboxes.

```
    <input type="checkbox"
       id="some_ID"
       name="some_ID"
       onchange="toggleLayer('some_IDTimeLayer')"/>
<label for="some_ID"
       title="some_Title">{{ some_Title }}</label>
```

So I wanted to try V2 so they would have to do a click test.  In the toggleLayer function I do:

```
grecaptcha.render('captcha_div', {
                        'sitekey': 'whatever_my_site_key_is',
                        'callback': function() {
                            wms_verification('','',this.layerId);
                        }
                    });
```

wms_verification does an ajax call to the server where I validate the token and return the response. If response.success then the box gets checked and the layer is toggled.  If not I handle the fact that it's a bot.  **This works fine for the initial click**.  However, when the box is changed again and i try to get a new token to verify I get:

```
Uncaught Error: reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element
```

I so researched:

- I saw the suggestion to use `grecaptcha.reset`

I tried that, it does remove the token from `grecaptcha.getResponse` however I still get the same error if I try to render the reCAPTCHA a second time.

- I found grecaptcha.execute

The error message was grecaptcha.execute only works with invisible reCAPTCHA.

- I found a suggestion to remove the element and recreate it

this also gives the same error.

- I found a suggestion to reload the recaptcha js

same error.

Has anyone had success using reCAPTCHA V2 with ajax on an element that has to check authenticity of the click **multiple times** with no reload of the page?

Comment: What's the point in checking it twice? The bot is not going to change into a human (And vice versa)

Comment: I simply can't seem to stop the bot from checking and unchecking the box.  There are several thousands of enable and disable over a few seconds, multiple times a day.  I am fully open to other solutions, reCAPTCHA doesn't seem to help.  I even created a python script to test when I was first using V3.  It had no issue at all checking the box, and got a reCAPTCHA score of .9.  So I began tracking, and every users score, human or bot it is getting a score of .9 as well.  That was the reason to try V2 where they have to get thru the click test.